# Update ADFS service name with AAD Connect. How?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

My ADFS farms are created by AAD Connect by below steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom#configuring-federation-with-ad-fs

However, I misconfigured the service name to "contoso.com" which the correct one is "sts.contoso.com". May I know the steps to change the ADFS service name?

Sorry for stupid question since I cannot find any well-documented info from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AD FS 2.0, go to refer [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1501.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-federation-service-name.aspx) and 3.0 at [this article](http://www.alsheppard.com/2014/07/changing-federation-service-name-in.html).

Make sure to also replace a new certificate which contains the new federation service endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much Thuan! Do you know how to update the configuration in AAD Connect as well?

Comment: What would you like to change? Sync rule or just general configuration? Get something here please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-change-the-configuration and also here to know if any technical constraints https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-best-practices-changing-default-configuration